# Angular - Change to inherited scope variable from parent not changing the variable in parent

Tags: angularjs

I have a parent controller where I have initialized a scope variable x = false. In the html that it refers to, I'm checking its value to show/hide an element. I'm also changing its value based on an ng-click.

within controller -

$scope.x= false;

within its html -

```
<div ng-if="x" ng-click="x= true">

    <my-directive x="x"></my-directive>

</div>
```

As you can see, I have a directive referred in it as well which inherits the "x" variable into its scope.

Directive definition:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('srcCommmandBar', ['myService', myDirective]);


function myDirective(myService){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {x: "="},
        replace: false,
        transclude: false,
        templateUrl: '<button ng-click="x = false"></button>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){


        }

    };
}
```

The template for the directive simply has a button which when clicked on changes the value of the scope variable, x to false.

My problem is that although it changes in the child scope "x", it does not change the parent scope "x". My understanding was that because of 2 way binding, the change in x will be cascaded to the parent. Am I wrong? How can I make this work?

Comment: Read up on "the dot."

Answer (score 0):

You should not bind raw variable to child scope.
You should wrap it in an object.
Otherwise when you change the x value in child scope, you lose the original reference.

```
-- templateUrl: '<button ng-click="x = false"></button>',  
++ templateUrl: '<button ng-click="x.value = false"></button>',
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there is a $parent variable, so I think you should be able to make it work with $parent.x